# Дефолтный конструктор и несоответствие размеров структуры, крэш

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с такой бедой сегодня. Собрал библиотеку libtorrent (статическую) с одними опциями (дефайнами),
а программу qbittorrent немножко с другими (я не думал что такое может быть).
Я собирал со стандартными опциями.

Проблема была в структуре web_seed_info.
У нее отсутствует конструктор копирования.

Он содержит поле

```
web_seed_info {
   //...
    policy::ipv4_peer peer_info;
   //..
   std::vector<> ....;
}
```

`peer_info` в свою очередь выглядит так:

```
...
    boost::uint32_t prev_amount_upload;
    boost::uint32_t prev_amount_download;
    peer_connection* connection;

#ifndef TORRENT_DISABLE_GEO_IP
    std::pair<const int, int>* inet_as;
#endif

mutable boost::uint32_t peer_rank;

//....
#ifndef TORRENT_DISABLE_ENCRYPTION
    bool pe_support:1;
#endif

#if TORRENT_USE_IPV6
    bool is_v6_addr:1;
#endif
```

В итоге при сборке библиотеки структура имела один размер, а при сборке самой программы - другой размер. Из-за чего дефолтный конструктор обламывался.

Так вот я подумал, как можно было бы избежать такой ситуации? Можно ли было бы добавить какую-нибудь проверку на этапе компиляции/ в рантайме? Чтобы я не тратил уйму времени на поиск ошибки. Или я сам себе злобный буратин?

В какой момент генерируется код дефолтного конструктора? При сборке стат. библиотеки или при сборке программы? Компилятор vs 2013

Answer (score 5):

Код конструкторов может участвовать в RVO (оптимизации возвращаемого значения), поэтому его окончательная генерация может произойти и на этапе компоновки.

Вывод - автор ССЗБ и должен внимательней относиться к конфигурации.

Comment: RVO происходит на этапе линковки?

Comment: @alexolutт сильно зависит компилятора и настроек. Подробности - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777863/do-rvo-and-copy-elision-only-work-within-one-compilation-unit-or-not

Comment: Крэш в моем случае не случился бы , если бы конструктор генерировался при компиляции библиотеки, или если я бы собирал динамическую библиотеку. Поскольку эта структура используется только внутри самой библиотеки, а в qbittorent не используется.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать `static_assert` объявление.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    long x;
};

static_assert( sizeof( A ) == 8, "Size of struct A shall be equal to 8" );

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке в случае, если размер структуры не равен 8 байтам:

```
main.cpp(9): error C2338: Size of struct A shall be equal to 8
```

Эти объявления вы можете заключить в препроцессорные директивы в соответствии с объявлением какого-нибудь имени.

Comment: да но мне придется синхронизировать этот размер при внесении изменений в библиотеку

Comment: @zenden2k Вы можете заключить static_assert объяваление ghtghjwtccjhyst lbhtrnbds, как, например, #ifdef.

Comment: может можно ввести в библиотеке массив скажем `int dummy[sizeof(struct)]` а в проге `extern dummy[sizeof(struct)]`

Comment: @zenden2k Делайте так, как вам удобно. Это уже дело вкуса.

Answer (score 3):

Взаимосвязанные модули надо собирать с такими настройками, чтобы участвующие во взаимодействии структуры данных имели не только одинаковый размер, но и одинаковый по смыслу набор членов, а так же выравнивание.
Иначе возможны ситуации, когда, в зависимости от настроек дефайнов размер одинаковый, но члены разные. И здесь могут приключатся любые чудеса в процессе работы, которые практически не поддаются отладке.

Например, скажем с одной стороны будет находится `bool pe_support:1;` (libtorrent), а с другой в том же месте структуры будет `bool is_v6_addr:1;` (qbittorrent).

Никакие `static_assert` по размеру тут не помогут. 
Просто надо собирать всё с едиными настройками. Вот и всё.